# Re-arrange code for desired output of squares?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested, square

I have created two squares based on user input so that one is a filled in square and one is a hollow square. As recommended by my professor, I set it up so that it will print one and then the other, however I need them to print on the same line now. How can I re-arrange my code so that they print beside each other instead of on top of each other?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class javaapplication30 {


public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int side = 0;
    System.out.printf("This program will display a full and an empty square given the side length.\n");
    System.out.print("Enter a side length: ");
    side = in.nextInt();

    //Filled square

      for (int i=1; i <=side; i++) {  
        for (int j=1; j <= side; j++) {
        System.out.printf("*");
    }
        System.out.println();
      }

     System.out.println();

    //Hollow square
    for (int i=1; i <=side; i++) {    //first row
        System.out.printf("*");
    }
    System.out.println();

    for (int j=1; j <= side-2; j++) {  
    for (int i=1; i <= side; i++) {  //middle rows
        if (i == 1 || i == side) {
        System.out.printf("*"); 
        }
        else {
            System.out.print(" ");
             }
    }
    System.out.println();     
    }


    for (int i=1; i <=side; i++) {  //last row
        System.out.printf("*");
    }
    System.out.println();



}
}
```

As an example, if I input the integer '5' my current program gives me

```
*****
*****
*****
*****
*****

*****
*   *
*   *
*   *
*****
```

Now I am trying to get the output

```
***** *****
***** *   *
***** *   *
***** *   *
***** *****
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: looks a little tricky but logical too

Answer (score 0):

> Totally Working code. You may Compile and Run it . I made it successfully Thank You.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
     class javaapplication30 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int side = 0;
        System.out.printf("This program will display a full and an empty square given the side length.\n");
        System.out.print("Enter a side length: ");
        side = in.nextInt();
      System.out.println();
        //Filled square
        int row = (side * 2)+1;
          for (int i=1; i <=side; i++) {  
            for (int j=1; j <= row; j++) {
                if(j==side +1){
                System.out.print(" ");
                continue;
                }if(((j>side+2) && (i >1 && i< side) && (j<row))){
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    continue;
                }else{
             System.out.print("*");
                }
        }
            System.out.println();
          }

         System.out.println();

    }
    }
```